# Interesting Isotope Error

Tags: google-chrome

I have an interesting and extremely annoying error occurring with my website.

A year ago I hired a programmer to integrate Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) into my website([www.Matthew.Pro](http://www.matthew.pro)). I can only do basic HTML and CSS and this was far beyond my abilities.

Isotope worked beautifully until about a week ago when it suddenly stopped. I've been unable to get it working or find any help on the matter. The programmer I used before is no longer available.

The site is hosted on Smugmug which has lots of it's own code entwined with my (stolen code) everywhere.

It's supposed to have filters that rearrange the images as it filters them. Also, the images should open in a flyout fashion, not load on a new page.

Here are the facts that make it interesting:

- I didn't make any change to my site when it stopped working - I wasn't logged in and was on vacation.
- It stopped working in Chrome for the pc. It still works on Chrome for mobile.
- It still works on IE8, although I'm told it isn't for IE10.
- It still works on Firefox.
- Other sites that use Isotope are working perfectly still.

I assume that the programmer I used made some changes that aren't cooperating with some new version of Chrome... but that's my uneducated guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developer Console on Chrome [says](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/5558/lgtae7a.png):

> Refused to execute script from
>   'https://raw.github.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.js'
>   because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict
>   MIME type checking is enabled.

And this answers your issue:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180007#c17

> In this case, it's telling the browser that it doesn't want its
>   content used in this way.

Temporary solution is [rawgithub.com](http://rawgithub.com/)

Use `https://rawgithub.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.js` as javascript source instead of https://raw.github.com/desandro/isotope/master/jquery.isotope.js or host `jquery.isotope.js` somewhere else.

> Note: It just work fine on Firefox

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick and accurate solution. It means a lot to me that a complete stranger would take the time to help me with my (noobish) problem. Cheers.